# Flutter Multi CheckBox List

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRAJE.png)]

Multi CheckBox List

I want to make this type of checkbox list Where I can Select One category that enables another catogery filter list to select options.

Could anyone help me to convert that logic into code ?

Comment: You must be asking for the issues that you're facing in your code and not the whole code by providing the design for that.

Comment: yes, I just need the help to build the logic in code.Design part I can manage @karan Mehta.

Comment: explain the flow. What do you want and what struggle do you facing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In the below-written code, I've provided basic & simple functionality of your requirement. So, there are multiple categories & each category has numerous sub-categories. Those multiple categories are selectable & those numerous sub-categories are also selectable. And they're linked respectively with each other. So it won't bother/conflict with any others.

Here's the sample code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const ChartPage(),
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

List<OuterList> outerList = <OuterList>[
  OuterList(
    category: "Category",
    innerList: <InnerList>[
      InnerList(category: "Shirting", selected: false),
      InnerList(category: "Lining", selected: false),
    ],
    selected: false,
  ),
  OuterList(
    category: "Brands",
    innerList: <InnerList>[
      InnerList(category: "Holland and Sherry", selected: false),
      InnerList(category: "Loro Piana", selected: false),
    ],
    selected: false,
  ),
];

class ChartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChartPage({super.key});

  @override
  ChartPageState createState() => ChartPageState();
}

class ChartPageState extends State<ChartPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return outer();
  }

  Widget outer() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Filters")),
      body: StatefulBuilder(
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, void Function(void Function()) setState) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: outerList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index0) {
              final OuterList outer = outerList[index0];
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  outer.selected = !(outer.selected ?? false);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                leading: Checkbox(
                  value: outer.selected,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    outer.selected = value;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                title: Text(outer.category),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final MaterialPageRoute<void> route =
                        MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return inner(index0);
                      },
                    );
                    await Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget inner(int index0) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Filters - ${outerList[index0].category}")),
      body: StatefulBuilder(
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, void Function(void Function()) setState) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: outerList[index0].innerList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index1) {
              final InnerList inner = outerList[index0].innerList[index1];
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  inner.selected = !(inner.selected ?? false);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                leading: Checkbox(
                  value: inner.selected,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    inner.selected = value;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                title: Text(inner.category),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OuterList {
  OuterList({
    required this.category,
    required this.innerList,
    required this.selected,
  });
  final String category;
  final List<InnerList> innerList;
  bool? selected;
}

class InnerList {
  InnerList({
    required this.category,
    required this.selected,
  });
  final String category;
  bool? selected;
}
```

Still, this is a sample code. So, only basic & simple functionalities are working. You've to modify this code according to further requirements.

Comment: If you think this is a helpful answer, consider upvoting the answer & if you believe this is a solution or supporting, consider accepting the answer.